# Change columnspan using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Is there a way I can change colspan of td using CSS or this needs to be done only in html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an HTML only property:

```
<td colspan="2">
```

There is no CSS equivalent of this (as far as I know.)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is possible.

colspan relates to the structure of the document - so it is handled by the HTML/XML.

css only handles things that are to do with the presentation of the document.

Have you considered using XSL/XSLT on the XML? They might be more useful.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/  may be this link will help you to solve this problem.